# Android: Programmatically remove my app from Device Administrator?

Tags: android, components, device-admin

I'm trying to add a button to my app to remove it from Device Administrator and am using the code below but my app just crashes.

Code:-

On Button Click:-

```
{
    ComponentName devAdminReceiver = new ComponentName(this, DemoDeviceAdminReceiver.class);
    DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    dpm.removeActiveAdmin(devAdminReceiver);
}
```

In the code above, DemoDeviceAdminReceiver is a class that extends DeviceAdminReceiver.

Error log:-

```
10-28 15:26:09.295: E/AndroidRuntime(26101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 15:26:09.295: E/AndroidRuntime(26101): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown admin: ComponentInfo{com.dragonnis.intellicover/com.dragonnis.intellicover.DemoDeviceAdminReceiver}
10-28 15:26:09.295: E/AndroidRuntime(26101):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1331)
10-28 15:26:09.295: E/AndroidRuntime(26101):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
10-28 15:26:09.295: E/AndroidRuntime(26101):    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.removeActiveAdmin(IDevicePolicyManager.java:2940)
10-28 15:26:09.295: E/AndroidRuntime(26101):    at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.removeActiveAdmin(DevicePolicyManager.java:183)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's as you do:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDPM.removeActiveAdmin(mDeviceAdminReceiver);
```

But you need to add these filters to the receiver in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
    </intent-filter>


@Override
public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
    return "Admin rights are beeing requested to be disabled for the app called: '" + context.getString(R.string.app_name) + "'.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. The intent filters are already present in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Device administrator is enabled just fine but trying to remove is still causing the crash.

Comment: Oh, fixed it. The issue was with the DeviceAdminReceiver class. I was using a separate class to enable device admin but when I tried to remove it I was using a different DeviceAdminReceiver which was not even enabled as device admin. Silly me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ViliusK can we disable device administrator permission of other app if my app has device admin permission ?

Comment: @rup35h No. It's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908226/programmatically-deactivate-a-device-admininstrator-in-android

Answer (score 0):

wrote an app with device admin enabled (DevicePolicyManager) and installed. But when I want to uninstall it, it returns failed with this message

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).