# Programmatically deactivate a Device Admininstrator in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, uninstallation, device-admin

Is it possible to programmatically deactivate a (third-party) [Device Administrator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) app?

I was able to retrieve all the apps with Device Administrator activated using the [DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) and [getActiveAdmins()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getActiveAdmins%28%29):

```
final DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
final List<ComponentName> adminList = dpm.getActiveAdmins();

for ( ComponentName app : adminList ) {
    Log.d(TAG, "App: ", app.getPackageName());
}
```

However, in order to deactivate them, I cannot use [removeActiveAdmin(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#removeActiveAdmin%28android.content.ComponentName%29), since it won't remove a component that is not my own app.

I was thinking to use an *Intent* and [startActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) in order to open the Device Administrator's deactivation page of that specific component I want to deactivate. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to programmatically deactivate a (third-party) Device Administrator app?

No. It is not possible to programmatically activate one, either.

> I was thinking to use an Intent and startActivity() in order to open the Device Administrator's deactivation page of that specific component I want to deactivate.

There is no entry point in the Settings app to directly go to the remove-a-device-admin screen, let alone a documented `Intent` action for it. You can add device administrators this way, but not remove them.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.java#6556

@Commonsware can u check the above link? It has one method to remove Admin of other Apps. Method is in Hidden mode. Although i am using Reflection pattern to use that method but it gives NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: "It has one method to remove Admin of other Apps" -- that is not what I see. "but it gives NoSuchMethodException" -- you may be running on an older device, as your link is to the `master` branch. I would expect you to get a `SecurityException` if the method exists.

Answer (score 5):

actually, it is possible to go directly to the admin screen, but i'm not sure how safe it is, as the API itself isn't available and the paths might change over different android versions and roms.

here's what i've tested:

this will go directly to the activate/de-activate screen of the app you choose:

```
final Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd"));
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,componentName);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

this will go to the list of admin apps:

```
final Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.DeviceAdminSettings"));
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

if anyone has a more official ,safer way to do it, please write it down.

those are quite risky, so you could first use this method:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
final PackageManager packageManager=context.getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos=packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
if(resolveInfos!=null&&!resolveInfos.isEmpty())
  try
    {
    final ResolveInfo resolveInfo=resolveInfos.get(0);
    intent=new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,componentNameResult);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    return true;
    }
  catch(final Exception e)
    {}
```

you can add try-catch for each of the methods, and if all failed , use:

```
final Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As also you've stated, using fixed paths is not really a good practice. However, as you suggested, I can use try-catch blocks to catch possible ActivityNotFoundException exceptions.

Comment: Oh.. I just discovered that, in some cases, also the Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS Activity may not exist.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS

Comment: @PaoloRovelli i've now added a little safer way to do it.

Comment: @PaoloRovelli really? weird. so there should be another fallback, to go to the settings of the device?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe it does not exist only on old devices. Anyway, you need to use a try-catch block (ActivityNotFoundException) also for Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS.

Comment: @PaoloRovelli ok, thanks for the warning. guess that you can have many try-catches for this...

Comment: @PaoloRovelli what is the intent of the device settings?

Comment: never mind. it's Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_SETTINGS

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
   ComponentName devAdminReceiver = new ComponentName(context, deviceAdminReceiver.class);
   DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
   dpm.removeActiveAdmin(devAdminReceiver);
```

You'll need to add this in manifest in your activity intent filter:

```
<action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
```

Comment: According to the Android documentation, you can only deactivate a component that is from your application, not components from third party applications.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#removeActiveAdmin(android.content.ComponentName)

Remove a current administration component. This can only be called by the application that owns the administration component; if you try to remove someone else's component, a security exception will be thrown.